# PDF button not showing on jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a jQuery datatable where it gets populated with data from the database.

I am trying to add a pdf button to the datatable  so I can export the data to pdf but the 'pdf' button is not showing.

This is my script that I use for my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').each(function () {
        $(this).prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:eq(0)"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "searching": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried adding the following to my script as explained here https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html but it is not showing:

```
buttons: [
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
```

Please assist how I can get the 'PDF' button to show. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you've added all `Javascript library` as per mentioned in [this link](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)

Comment: Please check if you got any errors in browser console first, then check if all prerequisities on the linked example had fulfilled.

Comment: have you add 
`dom: 'Bfrtip',` in the Datatable options?
 the `B` is the button

Comment: DataTable.net needs to make better documentation. I tried their simplest example, which didn't work. When I implemented the link given by Curiousdev that worked. I don't know if all of their examples work - someone needs to make edits to some of their web pages and put correct working examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

please make sure these js are included

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#example').DataTable( 
    { 
        dom: 'Bfrtip', 
        buttons: [ 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5' ] 
    }); 
} );
```